# Why do some apps on my computer think time is going faster than it should be?

Tags: time

Problem: In at least 2 apps, the time in the app is faster than actual time. Specifically, in a game called Marble Marcher and in the BOINC app. In Marble Marcher, a game that uses ray marching on fractals for its graphics and physics, the time is sped up 3 or 4 times actual time depending on how it's currently performing (it's always at >= 90% GPU when running this game). For BOINC, the time logs say that I use the program for 9 days each day.

Specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3800x
- GPU: AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT
- RAM: 32GB DDR4

For Marble Marcher, the CPU averages 10-20%. For BOINC, it's always at 100%.

Is there a reason why the time could be sped up for me (I haven't seen anyone else with this issue) or is it a problem with the apps?

Answer (score 1):

The developer of Marble Marcher is [aware of the problem](https://github.com/HackerPoet/MarbleMarcher/issues/26) but they wrote: "T*here is currently no further major development planned for this game. Please submit issues and pull requests to the [Marble Marcher Community Edition repository](https://github.com/WAUthethird/Marble-Marcher-Community-Edition/issues) instead.*"

You can [report the BOINC bug here](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/ReportBugs) but according to wiki the latest version is 5 years old so I doubt that they are actively working on it.

The reason is probably that this software wasn't written to take modern fast CPU's with many threads and cores into account.

In old games, and certain bad games like Fallout76, physics are tied to the framerate.
For an explanation why read [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3aq9we/comment/csfq27g/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and [that](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/96n2qp/comment/e41tbg4/).